# How can the phrase "그런가 하면" is translated as "furthermore"?

Tags: grammar, meaning

How can the phrase `그런가 하면` is translated as `furthermore`?
Does it relate to "은/는가 하면" grammar?

> 시골 장터에는 물건을 파는 사람들이 많았다. 
>  그런가 하면 물건을 사지 않고 그저 구경하는 사람도 적지 않았다.

Answer (score 3):

그런가 하면 is a fixed idiom, so it's best to just memorize the expression as a whole - I think it's more like "on the other hand" than "furthermore".

Literally, it is made of 그런가 (a question asking "Is it so?"), 하다 (= to say/think), and -면 ("if", although it's more like "when" here).

So, literally speaking, we can analyze it as "If we ask 'is it so?'", or maybe more naturally, "Now that we understand that, another thing to consider is..."

However, again, it's best to just consider it a fixed phrase.

Answer (score 0):

It is used 1) when the contents of the following sentence are either contrary to each other or simply different OR 2)in order to show an additional fact.

그런가 하면 can be translated and used in the different ways according to the context.

- 많은 경우, ~~ 하고 말할 수 있을 것입니다. 그런가 하면 이렇게 말하는 것이 좋을 경우도 있습니다. In many cases, it is possible to say ~~~. **In other cases,** it may be appropriate to say ~~.
- 그 도시의 남쪽은 현대적이고 화려하다. 그런가 하면 도시의 북쪽은 옛 정취를 느끼게 한다.
  The southern part of the city is very modern and fancy **while** the northern part is old fashioned.
- Some are ~~. Others are ~~. **Still others** are.
  어떤 사람들은 ~~ 겪습니다. 또 어떤 사람들은 ~~. 그런가 하면 자연재해로 인해 피해를 입는 사람들도 있습니다.